# share record with account owner of all child record which is associated with the parent

Tags: apex

```
public class ManuallyShareAccount {
    public static void manualShare(List<Account> newList)
    {
        List<Account> accList= new List<Account>();
        Set<Id> accSet= new Set<Id>();
        accList= [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN: newList];
        for(Account acc:accList)
        {
            accSet.add(acc.id);
        }
        List<Account> parentId= new List<Account>();
        List<Account> relatedAccount= new List<Account>();
       List<AccountShare> share= new List<AccountShare>();
        parentId=[SELECT ParentId FROM Account WHERE Id IN:accSet];
         relatedAccount=[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE ParentId IN:parentId AND ID NOT IN :newList];

        for(Account acc:newList)
        {
            for(Account acc1:relatedAccount)
            {
          AccountShare accshare= new AccountShare();
            accShare.AccountId=acc.id;

            accShare.UserOrGroupId=acc1.OwnerId;
                accShare.RowCause= Schema.AccountShare.RowCause.Manual;
                accShare.AccountAccessLevel='Read';
                accShare.AccountAccessLevel='Edit';
                share.add(accShare);
        }
        }
        if(share.size()>0)
            insert share;
    }

}
```

Comment: is this running inside a trigger?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need multiple queries, A single SOQL should suffice for your use case. Also as I can see you are using SOQL to querry ID which you already have in new list, which is overkill. If you have set AccountAccesLevel as Edit automatically you get read permissions too, You don't have to explicitly specify that.

```
public static void manualShare(List<Account> newList){
        List<Id> parentIdList = new List<Id>();
        for(Account acc : newList){
            parentIdList.add(acc.ParentId);
        }
        if(parentIdList.isEmpty()){
            return; //No Processing if Account has no parrent
        }
        Map<Id,Account> parentAccountMap = new Map<Account>([SELECT Id,OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id IN :parentIdList ]);
        List<AccountShare> accShareList = new List<AccountShare>();
        for(Account acc : newList){
            if(acc.ParentId!=null){
                AccountShare accShare = new AccountShare (AccountId = acc.Id , UserOrGroupId = parentAccountMap.get(acc.ParentId).OwnerId , 
                                    RowCause = Schema.AccountShare.RowCause.Manual , AccountAccessLevel='Edit');

            }

            accShareList.add(accShare);

        }
        insert accShareList;

}
```

Comment: When, I run this code inside a trigger, it says attempt to de-reference a null object in this line- UserOrGroupId = parentAccountMap.get(acc.ParentId).OwnerId